# When to use separate date and time instead of a single datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

If I want to store date and time, is it better to store them in a separate date and time or use a single datetime?

When should we use date and time instead of a single datetime?

I want to filter my queries either using date or time.

Comment: Depends on what you need to use it for really. There is no good reason just to use one by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In  SQL Server 2008 you have [date and time data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) so this becomes a non issue.

If it is good choice it really depends by your business and how you will query you data.

If for example you want to know all the orders places between 1 and 2 PM for any day using a separated `Date` and `Time` column will make it quicker

Comment: It's an interesting point with the queries being quicker just for time intervals. Do you have any data to substantiate that or is this based on an assumption reg index-structures?

Comment: Querying the data using a DATETIME column filtering just by time it would be more complicate as it would required a scan

Comment: Yep, I want to query my data using the date for any time or the time for any date.

Answer (score 12):

When you are talking about a moment in time, whether a universal moment, or a specific date and time on someone's local calendar, you use a `datetime`.  If you want to be sure that you are talking about an exact moment in time, regardless of the observer, then you use a `datetimeoffset`.

If you are storing just a `date` then you mean a date without a time component, meaning "any time on this date".

If you are storing just a `time` then you mean a time without a date component, meaning "this time on any date", or "this time on a date determined by some other means".

There is no practical purpouse to having both a `date` and a `time` that are about the same thing, sitting on the same row.  Just use a `datetime` for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you intentionally do not care about the time, it's more efficient to store this data as a date datatype.  Think a customer birthday column, there's not too many cases I can think of that would use this time.  If there happens to be a time attached to it (often a bug), this needs to be removed via a convert statement in order to do a compare.  It also consumes additional space if you don't need these values (3 bytes compared to 8).

I think it's similar to having a status code table with the id as a bigint instead of a tinyint or the like (depending on how many status codes you would plan to have).

It's just a matter of what you're using the data for, if you think there's a good chance you'll ever need the that data, then use datetime, otherwise use date.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing brilliant about separating date and time,

Better you save date and time in Same column,

Here they have discussed the same issue check it :  [are-there-any-good-reasons-for-keeping-date-and-time-in-separate-columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13840/are-there-any-good-reasons-for-keeping-date-and-time-in-separate-columns)

you can also get date and time separately by query

```
 SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111) as DatePart,
    convert(varchar(15), getdate(), 108) TimePart
```

Comment: Actually there are some very good reasons for splitting them up.  For example use the Date datatype when you don't care about time .. say dateofbirth .. that way your age calculations are a lot simpler.  The time data type is excellent for doing shift calculations.  I want everyone who worked at 5pm regardless of date.  You can split them up like you did but then they are varchar and certain calculations become much more difficult.  Which is greater '01:00:00 PM' or '12:30:00 AM'?